# Ansible 'when' fails to evaluate host var

Tags: conditional-statements, ansible

I'm trying to only execute a task if some host var has a value greater than 0

host-file

```
---
os:
  version_nr: 8
  version_name: jessie

dotdeb:
  priority: 100
```

task.yml

```
 - name: setup dotdeb preferences
   lineinfile: dest=/etc/apt/preferences
                  create=yes
                  line="{{ item }}"
   with_items:
              - "Package: *"
              - "Pin: release o=packages.dotdeb.org"
              - "Pin-Priority: {{ dotdeb.priority }}"
   when: dotted.priority > 0
```

But it seems that Ansible can't access the host variable for the 'preference' 
task.
Ansible is saying:

> error while evaluating conditional: dotdeb.priority > 0

I tried different quoting but nothing seems to work.
The host variables are working though, because 'os.version_name' is replaced properly in some task earlier.
Any suggestions?

Cheers Sebastian

Comment: Is your task conditional wrongly transcribed? You've got that as `when: dotted.priority` but your error states that it's `dotdeb.priority` that you're checking. What do you see if you run a debug on the variable before the task?

Comment: This was just a typo here at stackoverflow, but I found a solution.

Comment: What was your solution? If you think it might be useful for others then consider answering your own question.

Comment: Thanks for the debug hint! I used debug to output the var values and dotdeb.priority was undefined where as dotdeb_repo.priority works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem with the variable and the tag named equally.

I changed the var to

```
dotdeb_repo:
  priority: 0
```

and the tasks to

```
- name: setup dotdeb preferences
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/apt/preferences
              create=yes
                line="{{ item }}"
  with_items:
             - "Package: *"
             - "Pin: release o=packages.dotdeb.org"
             - "Pin-Priority: {{ dotdeb_repo.priority }}"
  when: dotdeb_repo.priority > 0
```

Now everything works as expected